# Regex not working in C# though working in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex

I have a regex which is working fine in Javascript

```
var dbId = "Test/Detail[@Name='ok'][@Details='ok2']/Submit";
dbId.replace(/(?:\[@Name='.+?'\]|\[@Details='.+?'\])/g,"");
```

But when i am trying it in C# it is not working

C#

```
Regex.Replace(dbId, @"(?:\[@Name='.+?'\]|\[@Details='.+?'\])", String.Empty);
```

Please help

Comment: Why do you have the @ outside your string in the C# code, this is used in the method docs only some of the time, and the reasoning is not explained. It could be causing your issues.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx

Comment: Help us to help you. What is not working? Are you getting compilation error? Not behaving right? Explain the problem. Provide error messages.

Comment: @Robadob, `@` creates a string literal, meaning anything inside the quotes is a valid character. It saves you escaping chars.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so replacement isn't done in place.

```
dbId = Regex.Replace(dbId, @"(?:\[@Name='.+?'\]|\[@Details='.+?'\])", String.Empty);
```

Assign the result back to `dbId`

---

Result: `Test/Detail/Submit`

Comment: +1, You don't know how many times I've done this exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help it works!! As i read the reply from 14V banged my head to the desk.